# is there a way to combine strings into a working save / delete funtion

Tags: vb.net

I am using two separate functions: one to save and one to delete. I would like to roll them into one function if possible even though VB gives me the wrong information. This is what I have so far:

```
Public Sub popup(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim ans As String
    ans = MsgBox(Operation & name, vbYesNo + Type, tital)
    If ans = vbYes Then

    End If

End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Save.Click
    'save
    Dim name As New String = "NAME_HERE"
        Dim Operation As New String = "Would you like to Save your Changes to "
        Dim tital As New String = "save this record "
        Dim Type As New String = vbQuestion
    
        Call popup(e, e)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Delete.Click
    'delete
    Dim name As New String = "NAME_HERE"
        Dim Operation As String = "Would you like to Delete your Record "
    Dim tital As New String = "Delete this record "
        Dim Type As New String = vbExclamation
    
        Call popup(e, e)
End Sub
```

Is the only way to roll it into one function to extend the ans = with strings like name2, Operation2, tital2, Type2 or is there a tidy solution?

Comment: thanks for the edits Laneville

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no overload of constructors for a String that does not have parameters. .Net allows you declare a String directly.

`vbExclamation` and `vbQuestion` are not a strings.

I have no idea what you expect to get with `Call popup(e, e)` Why would you want to send the EventArgs for the button to your popup Sub? You declared a message and a title in the button event but these values are never passed to the popup Sub. Those variables are local to the the button event and not visible in the popup method. Even if they were available, why would you want to concatenate the

When you declare your own methods (like popup) you can determine what needs to be sent to the method so it can do its work. These are the parameters of the method. When you call the method you pass arguments that match the expected parameters. The values in these arguments can be used inside your method.

BTW, the Call keyword is not needed except in special circumstanse.

I would like to show you the .Net way to use MessageBox instead of the old VB6 way. If you start to code in C# you will be comfortable with MessageBox.

I used a Select Case so it would be easy to add other message boxes, for example an Update message box.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim RetVal = CustomMB("Delete")
    If RetVal = DialogResult.Yes Then
        'Code to delete
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim RetVal = CustomMB("Save")
    If RetVal = DialogResult.Yes Then
        'Code to save
    End If
End Sub

Private Function CustomMB(MBType As String) As DialogResult
    Dim dr As New DialogResult()
    Select Case MBType
        Case "Delete"
            dr = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to Delete your Record", "Delete this record ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        Case "Save"
            dr = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to Save your Changes to ", "save this record ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        Case Else
            dr = MessageBox.Show("Sorry, no matching message box was found")
    End Select
    Return dr
End Function
```

Comment: i think i was tryig to be smart by passing the message box type as part of a string.  i shall try this out thanks Mary - If this works out how to i mark this as resolved ?

Comment: - question can you add the funtion in at module level and call it when required ?

Comment: Try it and see but I believe the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Your `popup` is a subroutine but I think it should be a function. You want to act on the result of the `MsgBox`. Here's a function that returns what the user selected:

```
Public Function Popup(name As String, operation As String, title As String, style As MsgBoxStyle) As MsgBoxResult
    Return MsgBox(operation & name, vbYesNo + style, title)
End Function
```

I've adjusted a few things in your code:

1. You cannot use `New` with `String` the way you are trying to (`Dim name As New String = "NAME_HERE"`)
2. I made `type` into a `MsgBoxStyle` variable

Here's the updated code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Save.Click
    'save
    Dim name As String = "NAME_HERE"
    Dim Operation As String = "Would you like to Save your Changes to "
    Dim tital As String = "save this record "
    Dim style As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.Question

    Dim result As MsgBoxResult = Popup(name, Operation, tital, style)

    Select Case result
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
            ' Save changes
        Case Else
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Delete.Click
    'delete
    Dim name As String = "NAME_HERE"
    Dim Operation As String = "Would you like to Delete your Record "
    Dim tital As String = "Delete this record "
    Dim style As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation

    Dim result As MsgBoxResult = Popup(name, Operation, tital, style)

    Select Case result
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
            ' Delete record
        Case Else
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: "You cannot use New with String" You can if you use one of the parameterized constructors the class provides.

Comment: @Mary thanks for that note, I updated the answer but was unaware of this. I didn't know basic data types could have constructors.